# Error decoding incorrect paddling with decode64, with padding present?

Tags: python, base64, decode

With the code that I am using, every time there is a `"?`" on data of the encoded message I get an error back `"Incorrect Padding"`. When using a decoder online I get the correct value for both `value1` and `value2` below, but for `value2` where there should be a `"?"` I get an exception instead.

The code is:

```
value1 = "Y29udGludWENCg=="
expected1 = b'continua\r\n'
value2 = "Y29udGludWE_DQo="
expected2 = b'continua?\r\n'

data1 = base64.b64decode(value1)
assert data1 == expected1
data2 = base64.b64decode(value2)
assert data2 == expected2
```

Decoding `value2` throws a `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding` exception, but the data has the right amount of padding (the length of `value2` is a multiple of 4).

Comment: Your base64 padding is indeed invalid. It can be repaired, which is what an online decoder might have done.

Comment: Just add the missing `'='`. Remove all non-Base64 characters first, then if the length is not a multiple of 4, add `=` characters until it *is*.

Comment: could you show me a exemple martijn?

Comment: Ah, I see what is going on: You have **URL-safe** data. Use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode()`.

Comment: In future, start with a complete [mcve]; I've filled in the blanks here once I figured out what kind of data you were expecting. Don't leave people trying to help you to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have standard Base64 data, you have **URL-safe** base64 data.

Base64 normally uses letters, digits and `/` and `+` characters, but the latter two carry special meaning in URLs, so an alternative [Base64url encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) is used that uses `-` and `_` characters instead.

Use the [`base64.urlsafe_b64decode()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64decode) to decode these strings:

```
data2 = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(value2)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import base64
>>> value2 = "Y29udGludWE_DQo="
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64decode(value2)
b'continua?\r\n'
```